# R Completing NAs with average of previous values

Tags: r, tidyr, na, zoo

I have looked at several similar questions on SO but can't seem to find a solution that works for me (though zoo and tidyr have gotten me the closest).  I have a df with a column containing a series of NA values and need to fill those values with the average of the previous 2 lags.  That new value needs to be included as one of the lags in the next record and so on.  So something like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
NA
NA
NA
```

needs to become

```
1
2
3
4
5
4.5 
4.75 
4.625
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, here is some sample data to play with.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x,
  1, 
  2, 
  3, 
  4,
  5,
  NA,
  NA,
  NA
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(is.na(df$x[i])){
        df$x[i] <- mean(c(df$x[i-1], df$x[i-2]))
    }
}

#    x
#   <dbl>
# 1  1   
# 2  2   
# 3  3   
# 4  4   
# 5  5   
# 6  4.5 
# 7  4.75
# 8  4.62
```